# jQueryUI sortable,draggable revert event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a problem with jQuqeryUI.
I would like to run some code whenever an element is dragged and dropped on an invalid target.
As far as I can see, there is no predefined event for this, but I have thought about combining information from following events: over, out, remove and stop, to achieve this. However that might sound like it's going to be a mess, is there a cleaner way yo do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a method to the [`revert` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#revert) as well, for example if we take the example demo like this:

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>I revert when I'm not dropped</p>
</div>
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p>Drop me here</p>
</div>​
```

Then on your draggable you can calculate whether to revert, like this:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({ 
    revert:  function(dropped) {
       var dropped = dropped && dropped[0].id == "droppable";
       if(!dropped) alert("I'm reverting, what a cruel world!");
       return !dropped;
    } 
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bVkwt/), the `dropped` parameter passed in is the element it was dropped on that's a `.droppable()`, it's just `false` if it landed anywhere else.

Or if you're using the [`accept` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-accept) you may want to calculate off that, like this:

```
var dropped = dropped && $(this).is(dropped.droppable('option', 'accept'));
```

This uses the accept selector and uses [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to see if the droppable matches.

[You can view a demo of that here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bVkwt/1/).

Comment: Hey thanks for that, it was just what I was looking for.
It is a nice undocumented feature ;)

Comment: Just out of curiosity - where did you find this? I can't find any of this in the manual.

Comment: @kastermester - The jQuery UI source for `.draggable()`, here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js#L199 :)