# draggable droppable with sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

we trying to integrate multiple drggable and droppable. we are using sortable for ease of clone functionality in this scenario. draggable once dropped need to be draggable again.

how do we limit sortable to receive only one element and revert to original if more than one dropped onto it.

look like out and over functions of sortable are misbehaving in that case.

commented line code is for disabling dropping second element on sortable. which is not working as expected.

Two issues when you enable my commented code:

1. draggable clone not reverting to original place after moving out of droppable.
2. draggable element moved from one droppable to another reverting to draggable's original place.

For a demonstration, see **[this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7mmburcx/29/)**

script:

```
//  jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery( document ).ready(function() { init();});
function init() {

  var mouse_button = false;
  jQuery('.ui-draggable').live({
      mousedown: function () {
          mouse_button = true;
      },
      mouseup: function () {

          if (jQuery(this).attr('data-pos') == 'out' && jQuery(this).attr('data-id')) {
              var p = jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).attr('data-id'));
              var offset = p.offset();
              jQuery(this).hide();
              jQuery(this).animate({ left: offset.left, top: offset.top, width: jQuery(this).width, height: jQuery(this).height }, 100, function () {
                  jQuery(this).remove();
                  $( ".ui-droppable" ).each(function() {
                    if($(this).children().length == 0) {
                      $( this ).removeClass("dontDrop");
                    }
                  });
                  //if(p[0].hasAttribute("draggable"))
                  p.draggable("enable");

             //     $('.ui-droppable').sortable('option', 'connectWith',$('.ui-droppable').not('.dontDrop'));
             //     $('.ui-draggable').draggable('option', 'connectToSortable',$('.ui-droppable').not('.dontDrop'));

              });
          }
          mouse_button = false;
      },
      mouseout: function () {
          if (mouse_button) {
              mouse_button = false;
          }
      }

  });

    jQuery( '.ui-draggable' ).draggable( {
      cursor: 'move',
      helper: 'clone',
      connectToSortable: ".ui-droppable",
      revert: function (event, ui) {
        }
    } );


    jQuery(".ui-droppable").sortable({
        cursor: "move",
        connectWith: ".ui-droppable",
        receive: function (event, ui) {

        if($(this).children().length >= 1) {

            $(this).children().addClass('filled');
            $(this).addClass('dontDrop');

            $( ".ui-droppable" ).each(function() {
              if($(this).children().length == 0) {
                $( this ).removeClass("dontDrop");
              }
            });
       //     $('.ui-droppable').sortable('option', 'connectWith',$('.ui-droppable').not('.dontDrop'));
       //     $('.ui-draggable').draggable('option', 'connectToSortable',$('.ui-droppable').not('.dontDrop'));
        }else {
            $(this).children().removeClass('filled');
        }
        if (jQuery(this).data().sortable.currentItem) {
                jQuery(this).data().sortable.currentItem.attr('data-id', jQuery(ui.item).attr("id"));
               // if(jQuery(ui.item)[0].hasAttribute("draggable"))
                jQuery(ui.item).draggable("disable");
            }

        },
        out: function (event, ui) {  if (ui.helper) { ui.helper.attr('data-pos', 'out'); } },
        over: function (event, ui) { ui.helper.attr('data-pos', 'in'); }
    });

  }
```

Comment: You typed: "_Three things are not working right after enabling commented code_" , yet the list that follows that line only has two list items - should there be a third?

Comment: It's still very unclear what you are trying to accomplish. I would not use `.droppable()`, except use `.sortable()` as you are in the fiddle. What is not clear, is the order and states. If I drag "Test 1" to a square, what should happen exactly?

Comment: Also, in your code, you switch from `jQuery()` to `$()` and I think that will cause problems for you.

Comment: Initial pass for code cleanup and seeing cleaner functionality. https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/7mmburcx/30/ Still not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example: [click here](https://codepen.io/EuniceBeijinho/pen/KyYawj)

You can user Jquery's [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) interactions to achieve what you want. Check the working example.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".ui-draggable").draggable(draggable_options) //make cards draggable

  $(".ui-droppable").droppable({ //handle card drops
    greedy: true,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      handleDrop(this, event, ui)
    },
    accept: function () {
      return checkIfShouldAcceptTheDraggable(this)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: two things what we needed that is why used sortable. when dragging out of any droppable it should return to its original position(in top list). another one is to disable original element when dropped on any droppable and when released outside, it should return to original place and activate it.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the new functionalities. Please don't forget to mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:([**Online Demo (fiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/b7ssuc0b/1/))

```
var draggable_options = {
  helper: 'clone',
  cursor: 'move',
  revert: 'invalid',
};

$(".ui-draggable").draggable(draggable_options);

$(".ui-droppable").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var $item = ui.draggable;
    $item.draggable(draggable_options)
    $item.attr('style', '')
    $(this).append($item)
  },
  accept: function() {
    return $(this).find("li").length === 0 // Your condition
  }
});

$(".textToImageRightPanel").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var $item = ui.draggable;
    $item.draggable(draggable_options);
    $item.attr('style', '');
    // Return to older place in list
    returnToOlderPlace($item);
  }
});

// Return item by drop in older div by data-tabidx
function returnToOlderPlace($item) {
  var indexItem = $item.attr('data-tabidx');
  var itemList = $(".textToImageRightPanel").find('li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-tabidx') < indexItem
  });
  if (itemList.length === 0)
    $("#cardPile").find('ul').prepend($item);
  else
    itemList.last().after($item);
}
```

Comment: as described above we do not want to remove element from above bar but disable it . also when dragged out it should return to top box location.

Answer (score 0):

Determining when to revert may be best done in `.draggable()` using `revert: function(){}`.

> **Function:** A function to determine whether the element should revert to its start position. The function must return `true` to revert the element.

You can do this:

```
  jQuery('.ui-draggable').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
    connectToSortable: ".ui-droppable",
    revert: function(item) {
      if (!item) {
        return true;
      } else {
        if (item.hasClass("dontDrop")) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
```

the revert function is passed `false` if the draggable item is not accepted. For example, if it is dropped on something that is not a target. If the draggable item is accepted, a jQuery Object is passed back.

See more: [jQueryUI sortable,draggable revert event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487155/jqueryui-sortable-draggable-revert-event)

The logic is a little confusing. If what is passed back is `false`, we return `true` to `revert` letting draggable revert the item to it's position. If what is passed back is not `false`, then it's an object we can test. If the target is "full", we revert. Otherwise we do not revert.

Sortable still wants add the item for some reason. May need to adjust to `update` and clear out any items that are not class `"filled"`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/7mmburcx/32/